# Uso delle preposizioni con la struttura "è difficile" + verbo all'infinito

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Usando il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/difficile) ho trovato che posso fare frasi con la struttura

> È + nome + difficile + preposizione + verbo all'infinito.

Per esempio:

> - È un'equazione difficile ***a*** risolversi.
> - È un lavoro difficile ***a*** eseguire.
> - È una lingua difficile ***da*** imparare.
> - È un argomento difficile ***a*** trattarsi.

La mia domanda è: cosa si deve fare con queste preposizioni se si pospone il nome al verbo? Si deve mantenere la stessa preposizione? Per esempio:

> - È difficile da imparare questa lingua.

Si deve usare un'altra preposizione? Ad esempio:

> - È difficile di imparare questa lingua.

Si deve togliere la preposizione? Per esempio:

> - È difficile imparare questa lingua.

Comment: Noterai che sono proprio due costruzioni diverse: in «È una lingua difficile da imparare» c'è un soggetto sottinteso a cui si attribuisce il predicato nominale “è una lingua difficile” modificato dalla proposizione (limitativa?) “da imparare” (potrebbe essere invece facile scriverla sui muri); in «È difficile imparare questa lingua», la forma corretta delle tre che proponi, “imparare questa lingua” è il soggetto del predicato “è difficile”.

Comment: Hai ragione, @DaG!

Answer (score 2):

Mantenere la preposizione ponendo il nome alla fine genera frasi che si utilizzano soprattutto nel parlato, spesso aggiungendo una virgola dopo il verbo:

> È difficile da imparare, questa lingua.

Se si desidera ottenere una frase grammaticalmente corretta, è necessario togliere la preposizione e rimuovere l'eventuale *si* riflessivo:

> È difficile imparare questa lingua.
>   È difficile trattare questo argomento.

Comment: È veramente grammaticalmente scorretta la frase "È difficile da imparare, questa lingua"?

Comment: @Charo sì, perché la regola dice che tra verbo e soggetto non ci vuole la virgola; d'altro canto, omettendola mantenendo comunque la preposizione equivale a dichiarare che "questa lingua" faccia parte della proposizione "da imparare" e non della principale ("è difficile").

Comment: A me pare sia una dislocazione a destra per dare più enfasi a "questa lingua". Ma forse questo sarebbe argomento per un'altra domanda.

Comment: @Charo certamente questa formulazione enfatizza "questa lingua", penso sia questo il motivo per il quale è utilizzata nonostante sia scorretta

Comment: @Stubborn, le dislocazioni a destra e a sinistra, più che “corrette” o “scorrette” – che sono categorie che non hanno molto senso nella linguistica moderna – sono strutture molto diffuse tipiche del registro parlato (o di quello scritto molto informale o che imita il parlato) e ampiamente studiate dai linguisti: http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/dislocazioni_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/

Comment: @DaG grazie per il tuo commento, con cosa suggerisci di sostituire "grammaticalmente scorrette" nella mia risposta?

Comment: Con niente. "genera frasi che si utilizzano soprattutto nel parlato". Se è di comune utilizzo, non è scorretto. Le leggi della grammatica (come quelle della fisica) sono descrittive e non prescrittive.

Comment: @edc65 grazie, ho aggiornato la risposta

Comment: Stubborn, scusa per non aver risposto prima, ma @edc65 ha risposto esattamente come avrei fatto io (e apprezzo la similitudine fra le “leggi” grammaticali e quelle fisiche).

Comment: @DaG non c'è problema, grazie ancora