# È grammaticalmente corretta la frase "È difficile da imparare, questa lingua"?

Tags: grammar

In [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/4081/707) si è detto che la frase

> È difficile da imparare, questa lingua

si usa nel parlato, ma è grammaticalmente scorretta. È veramente così? A me pare si tratti di una dislocazione a destra per dare più enfasi al soggetto «questa lingua». Questo fenomeno è frequente in altre lingue romanze, ma non so se in italiano si considera grammaticalmente scorretta. Ecco alcuni esempi:

> - Esempio in francese: «Qu'elle est jolie, cette fille!».
> - Esempio in castigliano: «Tiene conversación, ese peluquero» (esempio tratto da questo [libro](https://books.google.es/books?id=kjdw8yaGlsIC&pg=PA387&dq=%22tiene+conversaci%C3%B3n,+ese+peluquero%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zj7eVJKNFsntUq7TgogI&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22tiene%20conversaci%C3%B3n%2C%20ese%20peluquero%22&f=false)).
> - Esempio in catalano: «Diuen moltes mentides, els nens» (esempio tratto da [questo documento](http://www.romanistik.uni-freiburg.de/pusch/zfk/20/12_Mayol.pdf)).

Answer (score 9):

Come accennavo in un commento a quel post, le dislocazioni a destra (come questa) e a sinistra («A Gigi le cose gliele dobbiamo sempre dire mille volte»), più che “corrette” o “scorrette” – che sono categorie che non hanno molto senso nella linguistica moderna – sono strutture molto diffuse tipiche del registro parlato (o di quello scritto molto informale o che imita il parlato) e [ampiamente studiate dai linguisti](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/dislocazioni_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/): «un tipo di costruzione tipica della lingua parlata (ma riscontrabile, fin dall’italiano antico, anche in alcune varietà di quella scritta ...), nella quale alcuni costituenti (l’oggetto o un complemento indiretto, ma anche altri) non occupano le posizioni normalmente previste dalla struttura della lingua (nel caso dell’italiano: Soggetto-Verbo-Oggetto, o SVO), ma sono spostati in posizione «non canonica» ... per effetto di una focalizzazione ..., svolgendo così una particolare funzione pragmatica ed esprimendo un particolare significato in relazione alla progressione dell’informazione».

A questo punto, usarle o no dipende esclusivamente dal contesto e dalla padronanza del registro appropriato, non diversamente da quello che accade in ambito lessicale con la scelta tra “mamma” e “madre”, o tra “faccia”, “viso” e “volto”.

Comment: Tuttavia, l'articolo dell'Enciclopedia Treccani che hai citato, afferma: «la dislocazione a destra del soggetto – frequente in francese ma possibile in italiano solo in alcune varietà diatopiche, dato che in italiano manca un clitico che faccia da soggetto».

Comment: Come afferma [questo articolo](http://www.romanistik.uni-freiburg.de/pusch/zfk/20/12_Mayol.pdf), la dislocazione a destra del soggetto è anche frequente nella mia lingua, il catalano, ma si fa senza la presenza di un clitico che faccia da soggetto nella frase.